# Creating Customer on Balanced Payments

Tags: balanced-payments

I am confused by the Balanced Payment documentation, specifically for creating customers:

The Balanced docs say to create a customer with this code:

```
$marketplace = Balanced\Marketplace::mine();
$customer = $marketplace->customers->create(array(
            'address' => array( 
            'postal_code' => '48120', 
          ), 
          'dob_month' => '7',
          'dob_year' => '1963',
          'name' => 'Henry Ford',
         ));
```

The goal is to get a json response:

```
{
"customers": [
    {
        "address": { 
            "postal_code": "48120", 
            //more key -> value pairs
        }, 
        //more key -> value pairs
        "href": "/customers/CU3SSJgvA5Z69kt05MusbPeE", 

    }
```

The problem that I am having is that I cannot find any reference as to how to send the info to Balanced.  Do I use balanced.js to tokenize it the same way I tokenize a credit card?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/api/customers/#create-a-customer . You would use one of the clients, such as the Python or PHP clients found at https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/getting-started/#client-libraries .

Balanced.js is just for card tokenizations to aid with PCI-compliance -- using it, sensitive card information is posted directly to Balanced and never has to touch your own servers.